# Load Balancing DNS Servers UDP on HAProxy

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, haproxy, udp

I have read quite a few articles about UDP load balancing. I didn't find helpful information. (find a few answers which are quite old info I guess)
My question is does HAProxy support the UDP? If Yes how can we load balance the DNS server?
else then what is the best alternative to load balance the DNS server?

More information: I am able to query DNS with TCP protocol and I got the answer.
EX: dig +tcp  @10.1.1.17 [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) A

Once I remove the +tcp I get the below snippet.

{
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.1.1.17 [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

}

Note: 10.1.1.17 dummy IP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP listeners are supported, but only in a very specific use-case ; the syslog protocol and not for other UDP protocols/use-cases such as DNS

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-bind

```
            - 'udp@'   -> address is resolved as IPv4 or IPv6 and
              protocol UDP is used. Currently those listeners are
              supported only in log-forward sections.
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response !!